# Appending a list to itself in Python

Tags: python, list, append

I want to attach a list to itself and I thought this would work:

```
x = [1,2]
y = x.extend(x)
print y
```

I wanted to get back `[1,2,1,2]` but all I get back is the builtin `None`. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Python v2.6

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`x.extend(x)` does not return a new copy, it modifies the list itself.

Just print `x` instead.

You can also go with `x + x`

Answer (score 2):

`x.extend(x)` modifies `x` in-place.

If you want a new, different list, use `y = x + x`.

Answer (score 1):

or just:

```
x = [1,2]
y = x * 2
print y
```

Comment: You are creating `[x, x]`, if one element of `x` changes, it will change in the other index of `y`, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: @Schorsch That is true for `[x] * 2` which is equivalent to `[x] + [x]`. However, `x * 2` is equivalent to `x + x` which creates a "shallow" list of values in this case.

Answer (score 0):

x.extend(x) will extend x inplace.

```
>>> print x

[1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new copy of the list try:

```
x = [1,2]
y = x + x
print y # prints [1,2,1,2]
```

The difference is that `extend` modifies the list "in place", meaning it will always return `None` even though the list is modified.